# Messed audio settings, now i have no sound

Tags: debian, audio, xfce

I was trying to configure sound and while changing settings, specifically controllers, i messed it and now i have no sound.

However, when i use the command `speaker-test -Dplug:front -c2 -l5 -twav` it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the `sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils reset 0` command.